# Why can't we pass a reference from native C++ to C++/CLI?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I use a native C++ code base from C#, with a C++/CLI wrapper built around it (with Visual Studio 2013). There are two projects:

- NativeCodeBase: simple C++ project set to be built into a static lib.
- ManagedWrapper: C++/CLI project referencing NativeCodeBase.

I have the following native "interface" in NativeCodeBase:

```
class ITest {
    virtual void Foo(const std::string& str, MyEnum me) = 0;
}
```

For which I have a native implementation in the ManagedWrapper project.
In the header:

```
class TestManaged : public ITest {
    virtual void Foo(const std::string& str, MyEnum me) override;
}
```

In the cpp:

```
void TestManaged::Foo(const std::string& str, MyEnum me) {
    int length = str.length();
}
```

The MyEnum enum is used both in native and managed code, so in its implementation I use a conditionally compiled C++/CLI extension, to make it usable from C#:

```
#ifdef _MANAGED
    public
#endif
    enum class MyEnum : unsigned char
    {
        Baz = 0,
        Qux = 1
    };
```

In my native code I have a reference to `ITest` and call its `Foo` function with a local `std::string` variable. When Foo is called, I can see in the debugger that the string passed as an argument is a valid string object.

The call is similar to this:

```
void Bar(ITest& test) {
    std::string str = "test";
    test.Foo(str, MyEnum::Baz);
}
```

However, if I put a breakpoint at the beginning of `TestManaged::Foo`, the debugger says that str has `<undefined value>`, and the `length()` call crashes with undefined reference error in the `<xstring>` header in the following function:

```
size_type length() const _NOEXCEPT
{   // return length of sequence
    return (this->_Mysize);
}
```

The debugger displays `<undefined value>` for the `this` pointer as well.

What can be the reason for this? References somehow get corrupted when passed between the two libraries?

(Additional info: I used not to build the NativeCodeBase project as a separate lib, but linked all the source files from it into the CLI project, and the same code base worked without any problem. It started failing since I configured it to be built into a separate lib and added a reference in the CLI project to the native one.)

Comment: Are there any runtime problems (i.e. outside of its execution in the debugger)?

Comment: "undefined reference error" is hard to interpret.  But the basic diagnostic here is that the std::string definition is not the same on either end of the divide.  A side effect of compiling code with different settings or a different version of C++ library.  Iterator debugging is always a strong candidate, off in one but not the other.

Comment: The real function has other parameters, for instance the second parameter is a float, and that gets corrupted too, it contains some garbled value at the callee side.

Comment: I figured out the problem, details in answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem wasn't with the reference itself. The problem was with the second enum parameter. The implementation of the enum class looked like this:

```
#ifdef _MANAGED
    public
#endif
    enum class MyEnum : unsigned char
    {
        Baz = 0,
        Qux = 1
    };
```

The #ifdef directive was put there in order to create a native enum when built for native C++, but create a CLI enum when built for C++/CLI.

This worked well when all the source files were linked to the CLI project and every piece of source was built again for the CLI project. However, this approach does not work any more when I want to use the native lib from the CLI side.

I guess the problem was that the same header was built differently in the two libraries, so the caller and the calle saw a different binary interface of the object, thus the arguments got garbled when passed. Is this correct?

I got rid of the conditionally compiled public keyword and it started working properly again.

Comment: There's really little point in putting this detail in an answer. It is only of interest to you today, right now. Nobody else will benefit from this in the future. The question is unanswerable because the actual problem was contained in code not present in the question. Feel free to delete the whole lot.

Comment: I think it can give a hint to other people that when function arguments get garbled when interoping between C++ and C++/CLI the problem can be conditionally compiled C++/CLI extensions.

Comment: Why don't you re-write the question to actually include the problematic code. That might be helpful.

Comment: I updated the original question with information about the conditionally compiled enum class.

Comment: That is an improvement